# inheriting constructors from base class?

Tags: c++

I have a Rectangle class and a Square class that both have the same argument in a constructor (name,width,height)

So I thought of create a Base class called Shape and define the constructor in Shape.h and let Rectangle class and a Square class inherit the constructor from Shape class.

The problem I am facing is, I don't really know how to inherit the constructor from Shape class to Rectangle and Square class.

Pardon me if I am asking a simple question as I am still new to C++.

**Shape.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef Assn2_Shape_h
#define Assn2_Shape_h


class Shape {

public:
 Shape() {
     name = " ";
     width = 0;
     height = 0;
 }

Shape(std::string name, double width, double height);

private:
    std::string name;
    double width,height;
};
#endif
```

**Rectangle.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef Assn2_Rectangle_h
#define Assn2_Rectangle_h


class Rectangle : public Shape {
//how to inherit the constructor from Shape class?
public:
 Rectangle() {

 }

private:

};
#endif
```

**Square.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef Assn2_Square_h
#define Assn2_Square_h


class Square: public Shape {
//how to inherit the constructor from Shape class?
public:
   Square() {

    }

private:

};
#endif
```

Comment: default constructor of base will be called automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can [inherit constructors from a base class](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#inheriting). It is an all-or nothing operation, you cannot pick and choose:

```
class Rectangle : public Shape 
{
  //how to inherit the constructor from Shape class?
 public:
  using Shape::Shape;
};
```

This implicitly defines the constructors as if they were in the derived type, allowing you to construct `Rectangles` like this:

```
// default constructor. No change here w.r.t. no inheriting
Rectangle r; 

// Invokes Shape(string, double, double)
// Default initializes additional Rectangle data members
Rectangle r("foo", 3.14, 2.72);
```

This is a C++11 feature and the compiler support may vary. The latest versions of GCC and CLANG support it.

Comment: VG +1. I think you should make the point that this implicity defines `Rectangle::Rectangle()`. It's not that clear in Stroustrup's paper either, only in a code comment.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking how to *invoke* them rather than 'inherit' them. The answer is with the : syntax:

```
Rectangle() : Shape() {
// ...
}
```

where the argument lists in each case are whatever you need

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks. I'm not up to date with C++11.